# Apply default style and onClick change style of a button -Angular 4

Tags: css, angular, components

I have one button, i want to apply a default style of a button and when user click on a button change a button style color to red and background-color to white. Blow is my .css and component.

```
.btn-default {
  color: white;
  background-color: blue;

}

.btn-change {
  color: Red;
  background-color: white;
}
```

Component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  bntStyle: string;
  AppComponent() {

   this. bntStyle = 'btn-default';
  }
  submit() {
    this.bntStyle = 'btn-change';

  }
```

.html

```
<div>
 <button name="Save" [ngClass]="['bntStyle']" (onClick)="submit()">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are binding the string 'btnStyle'. Instead, you should bind the filed:

```
<div>
    <button name="Save" [ngClass]="[bntStyle]" (click)="submit()">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: @Ayala- I have modified code [ngClass]="[bntStyle]" but its not working.

Comment: Use also (click) instead of (onClick)

Comment: i tested this and square brackets are not required after the =.  [ngClass]="btnStyle" works for me

Answer (score 3):

Fire change (`OnClick`) to (`click`) and then use following code snippet.

```
<div>
 <button name="Save" [ngClass]="[bntStyle]" (click)="submit()">Submit</button>
</div>
```

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ya8swi?embed=1&file=app/app.component.html)**

Answer (score 2):

I know this is too late for the solution, but this might help others.

.html

```
<button [ngClass]="[btnStyle]" (click)="submit()">Submit</button>
```

.css

```
.btn-default {
  color: white;
  background-color: blue;
}

.btn-change {
  color: Red;
  background-color: white;
}
```

.ts
*(if-else inside submit function is to toggle between the styles)*

```js
import { Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
 
 btnStyle = 'btn-default';

  submit() {
    if(this.btnStyle == 'btn-change') {
      this.btnStyle = 'btn-default';
    } else {
      this.btnStyle = 'btn-change';
    }
  }
}
```