# How should I do two way binding for contenteditable div so that we can access the content and make changes when onclick event occurs?

Tags: angular

Template File containing contenteditable div and button clicking on which the text should be bold:

```
<button class="btn btn-light" (click)="onBoldClick()">
<b>B</b>
</button>
<div [(ngModel)]="content" name="fieldName" ngDefaultControl class="container editor">{{content}}
</div>
```

TypeScript File:

```
 export class EditorComponent implements OnInit {
    
    content:string="";
    
    constructor() { }
    
    ngOnInit(): void {}
    
    onBoldClick(){
    console.log(this.content.bold());
    }
 }
```

Comment: What effect or action do you want to achieve when clicking the button?

Comment: It is a contenteditable div .I forgot to mention it in the code here.The effect I want to achieve is that like in text editors we click on a bold button and text becomes bold that same effect I want to acheive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple approaches you can use here:

1- you can add style on click for that specific div element using **ngClass**:

```
<button class="btn btn-light" (click)="onBoldClick()"><b>B</b></button>
    <div [(ngModel)]="content" [ngClass]="[divStyle]"  name="fieldName" ngDefaultControl class="container editor" >{{content}} 
    </div>``
```

// ts file

```
 divStyle: string;
    onBoldClick(){
    this.divStyle = 'font-weight:bold;';
    }
```

**[ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48243620/apply-default-style-and-onclick-change-style-of-a-button-angular-4)**

2- also, you can edit style for an HTML element using viewChild:
**[ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52541318/angular-how-to-change-css-using-viewchild)**

**Update**
[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mybv7g?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: It is a contenteditable div .I forgot to mention it in the code here.The effect I want to achieve is that like in text editors we click on a bold button and text becomes bold that's the exact thing I want to do.

Comment: Sir one more thing what if we have to bind one more property and apply both simultaneously on different click then what should be done??

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fhfni7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: yes sir something like this but what if I use this code given below  and want the same effect that was produced by buttons. How this would be  achieved using ngOnChanges or something else.

    ``<select>
    <option value="bold">Bold<option>
    <option value="italic">Italic<option>
    </select>``

Comment: Add change event for the select tag, So every time user change selection the event will trigger and call the change method, I will provide a stackBlitz example

Comment: Check, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fhfni7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts